# Как console log работает без вызова с параметром?

Tags: javascript

Недавно встретил в интернете такой коментарий:

```
.then(msg => console.log(msg))
это то же самое что и
.then(console.log)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает данная конструкция. Возможно есть какое-то название этого способа применения.

Comment: `msg => чтототам` это функция, принимающая один параметр. `console.log` это тоже функция, принимающая один параметр. Так что они полностью взаимозаменяемы в тех случаях, где ожидается функция с одним параметром

Comment: до недавнего времени это было не одним и тем же, и второй вариант вызывал exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял Вас интересует вторая запись

```
 .then(console.log)
```

здесь в функцию `then` передается ссылка на функцию `log`, находящуюся в объекте `console`, эта функция будет вызвана асинхронно потом.

при этом код функции then примерно такой, setTimeout я тут выбрал для ясности, чтобы показать асинхроность происходящего:

```
  waiter.then = function(callbackFunc) {

    setTimeout(function() {
          callbackFunc("finish");
    }, 1000);

  }
```

Эта концепция называется [функциональное программирование](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), функция принимающая на вход функцию называется [функцией высшего порядка](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0)

В **javascript** это на каждом углу, и это очень удобно, лучше как можно раньше с этим разобраться

Answer (score 0):

```
var handlerThen = msg => console.log(msg);
.then(handlerThen)

var handlerThen = function(msg) { console.log(msg); };
.then(handlerThen)

var handlerThen = console.log;
.then(handlerThen)
```

будут делать одно и то же.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется стрелочная функция. `console.log()` тут не причём.
    var handletThen = function(msg) {

```
}.then(...) 

var handlerThen = msg => console.log(msg);
.then(handlerThen)
```

В начале мы видим стандартную запись функции. Но чтобы не было таких обширных записей, в `ES6` добавили стрелочные функции, которые записываются вот так: `(аргументы) => {код}`, это всё таже функция, но у неё есть некоторые отличия от обычной, о которых вы можете почитать в интернете, я же скажу, что если в такую функцию вы передаёте 1 параметр, то скобки можно опустить, то есть: "argument => {...}", такая запись не вызовет ошибку. Если аргументов больше, `()` обязательны!!: `(argument1, argument2) => {...}`, и также если аргументов нет, скобки тоже обязательны!: `() => {...}`. Если данная функция записана как: `() => {return console.log("Hello!")}`, её можно сократить до `() => console.log("Hello")` и парсер сам поймёт что данную строку нужно вернуть как результат работы стрелочной функции.